# How to chain classes with commands

Tags: puppet, librarian-puppet

I have the following class which installs mysql and sets up a user called user but when the create-database commands runs the user has not been created yet.
How do i chain the commands so that the user is created before create-database tries to use it?

```
class { '::mysql::server':
  package_name            => 'mariadb-server.x86_64',
  root_password           => 'root',
  remove_default_accounts => true,
  override_options        => $override_options,
  restart                 => true,
  users                   => {
    'user@%' => {
      ensure                   => 'present',
      max_connections_per_hour => '0',
      max_queries_per_hour     => '0',
      max_updates_per_hour     => '0',
      max_user_connections     => '0',
      password_hash            => '...',
    }
  },
  grants                  => {
    'user@%/*.*' => {
      ensure     => 'present',
      options    => ['GRANT'],
      privileges => ['ALL'],
      table      => '*.*',
      user       => 'user@%',
    },
  }
}->
exec { 'create-database':
  creates => '/opt/dbinstalled',
  command => '/usr/bin/mysql -u user -puser < /create-db.sql'
}
```

I am using the puppetlabs-mysql package to install mysql.

Comment: if you are using the puppetlabs-mysql module you should check out the defined type it ships with: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-mysql/blob/master/manifests/db.pp, it could take care of both the user and the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the documentation for the `require, before, subscribe, notify` metaparameters. They are used to describe resource ordering (`before, notify`), or resource ordering and failure if the dependency fails (`require, subscribe`). Note the `subscribe, notify` metaparameters are only available for some resource types (`exec, service`, etc.).

In this instance, you would do the following to chain a class:

```
exec { 'create-database':
  creates => '/opt/dbinstalled',
  command => '/usr/bin/mysql -u user -puser < /create-db.sql',
  require => Class[::mysql::server],
}
```

But you really only need the dependency on the user resource:

```
exec { 'create-database':
  creates => '/opt/dbinstalled',
  command => '/usr/bin/mysql -u user -puser < /create-db.sql',
  require => User[username or array of users],
}
```

Also you probably only want to create the database once, so we can give it a `subscribe/refreshonly` for idempotence:

```
exec { 'create-database':
  creates     => '/opt/dbinstalled',
  command     => '/usr/bin/mysql -u user -puser < /create-db.sql',
  subscribe   => User[username or array of users],
  refreshonly => true,
}
```

Note that if you change the `user` resource that the `create-database` is subscribed to this will rerun the `exec` resource, so look into the `unless, onlyif` parameters for `exec` as other methods to establish idempotence.

Comment: I ended up having to add require => [Mysql_grant['user@%/*.*'], Mysql_user['@user.mdlocal']]

Comment: Oh that is the actual resource. I should have checked what the actual resources generated by the class are. Have you tried making the `exec` resource idempotent or is that not necessary?

Comment: /opt/dbinstalled gets created during this command so creates should stop it being run at the next provision.

Comment: Good point; I rarely use the creates attribute so I forgot it existed.